# How to display results for each question based on answers

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmyadmin

I'm still new to programming and need to create a quiz feature for my website project and need to display a result after the user answers each question.

For example Q - Do you gym regularly? If the user answers yes or no it will store the answer and go onto the next question, at the end when the user hits submit it will display all the information relating to the questions depending if the user answered 'yes' or 'no'.

I have set up a table in phpmyadmin for the questions and a question id, do I need a separate table for the answers? or would I be best hardcoding the questions and just storing the answers?

My website is running on localhost using Apache my database is set up on phpmyadmin with users etc. Majority of my features are using php. From what I have found online most quiz features use javascript and I'm not very familiar with the language so open to any suggestions.

I would like to be able to store the answers in the database so when the user logs in the info is there for them. Any help is appreciated because my coding skills are not amazing.

Bellow is how I have it set up atm just using html but not sure how to add the php or javascript etc

```
<div class="col-md-6">
            <form>
                <h4>Did they have any social media accounts</h4>
                <div class="help-tip">
                <p>Such as facebook, instagram, twitter, snapchat etc</p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio" checked> <span class="label-text">Yes</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio"> <span class="label-text">No</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </form>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
            <form>
                <h4>Where they the main name on utility bills?</h4>
                <div class="help-tip">
                <p>Bills such as electricity, oil, telephonee, internet</p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio" checked> <span class="label-text">Yes</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio"> <span class="label-text">No</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but StackOverflow is not a code writing service. We are here to help you with any specific problem you might have, not to do the whole project for you. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask As to your more specific question: I would store both questions and answers in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your future plans and number of questions, it is probably better to store those questions (maybe also their possible answers ? ) in database since it gives your more flexibility in the future to change those questions. Depending if those questions are all yes/no or different answers are possible, maybe create another table that would map possible answers to questions.
Since each question can be answered multiple times by different users and so on you should create another table for question answers.In this case storing one answer in one row sounds like the best solution from my point of view (it might not be :D ). It would have answer_set_id that would tie it together to one answer_set (and also to user,answer_set table that could have id, user_id and possibly time), this depends on the amount and type of data and also what are you planning to do with it.